# How to make simple listview or listbox that is rows are editable as textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, listbox, contenteditable

I am looking for a simple solution that will allow me to edit content of listbox or listview in

C# .net 4.5 WPF application

i came across `listView1.LabelEdit = true;` however there is no such option in wpf

and datagrid is not as easy as using listbox or listview

so are there any easy solution for this ?

ty very much

**example listbox and listview**

```
<ListView  Name="lstBoxTableColumnValues" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="462" Margin="315,76,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="214"/>
<ListBox Name="lstBoxSelectedColumnDistcintValues" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="462" Margin="534,76,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="282"/>
```

**example use**

```
lstBoxTableColumnValues.Items.add(string);
lstBoxSelectedColumnDistcintValues.Items.add(string);

string asdsa=lstBoxTableColumnValues.Items[0];
asdsa=lstBoxSelectedColumnDistcintValues.Items[0];
```

**So lets say after i filled Listbox i will click any index item i want and edit its content. And when i retrieve that particular index i will get my edited value.**

Comment: Are you looking for listBox1.ItemSource??

Comment: You need to have a content template of TextBox.  Cannot just add Items.